# convert a sql query that returns 500k records into a csv fast (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm using this method that converts a ruby object into a csv. It works great for an object with under 5k records, but once you get to 250k to 500k records, it takes 30 minutes to process the csv. Any ideas on how to make this run super fast?

```
def to_csv(result)
  unless result.nil?
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << result[0].attribute_names
      result.each do |row|
          csv << row.attributes.values
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You might want to directly use a PostGreSQL / MySQL function to export the records in the DB: http://support.spatialkey.com/export-data-from-database-to-csv-file/

Comment: I totally agree, you should use an SQL processing, it will be the fastest solution !

Comment: how do I send the csv back to the user? Could you elaborate on how I would do this? I tried to do this and send the csv back to the user but it's not working: def test
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("COPY ('select * from table') TO 'query.csv' WITH CSV HEADER")
    end

Answer (score 2):

There might be a RAM issue as your data is too large

```
Find_each() and find_in_batches({options})
```

for result instead of loading all record once in RAM. 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_in_batches
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Hope these links will help you.

Answer (score 1):

From the `attribute_names` and `attributes.values` calls I assume you're generating CSV from `ActiveRecord` instances. The area to target is probably how you are building up `result` rather than how you are generating the CSV.

If you are using active relation to build `result`, for example using something like `MyObject.where(x: 1)` then you could certainly consider using [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) instead to get batches of objects to write to csv. (Note: if you are doing `MyObject.all` then you need to just use `MyObject.find_each`)

If you are using `find_by_sql` then you could create the batches yourself using repeated calls to `find_by_sql` with "limit 1000 offset 0" suffixed.

Ultimately though, as suggested in the comments, if you can do it directly from the database layer that's probably the fastest solution ultimately.

Comment: thanks Shadwell. The batch processing is interesting and you enlightened me on that subject. However the SQL query is only taking 2 minutes. It's the writing to the CSV that's taking forever (28 out of 30 minutes)

Comment: Does that 2 minutes include getting all the objects from the database into memory though? Or just an evaluation of how long the query takes to run? (And you're welcome :) )

Comment: it's an evaluation of how long the query takes to run

Answer (score 1):

Also you can generate CSV file with the pgAdmin:

```sql
COPY (SELECT column_a,column_b FROM whatever) TO '/tmp/dump.csv' WITH CSV HEADER
```

Comment: You should probably explain how to perform this query from the Ruby code of the question.